# Get nearby street addresses within a radius

Tags: api, location, reverse-geocoding, street-address

I would like to retrieve a list of all the street addresses within a small range on a geopoint.

A scenario for use is for a user to select his/her current address from a list of addresses (within say 50 meters) of current location, since location retrieval is not going to be accurate enough.

I am wondering if that is possible using Google maps API?
Otherwise does anyone knows an alternative API that I can use for this purpose?

From what I've seen, although the Google maps reverse geocoding service returns a number of "addresses" for a geopoint they are usually just different representations of the address, rather than addresses near location.

I've seen some similar questions on SO but none had the answers I am looking for.

Comment: which version of the API are you using? JS? Android? old Flash? other?

Comment: JS Google Maps API v3 is the one I used for testing. If I find a solution I will implement on iOS and Android devices. I'm not strict to using Google's API, as long as I can get the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get the kind of results I was looking for using a combination of APIs.

First I get the names of the nearby streets using [Geonames' "Find nearby streets"](http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearbyStreetsOSM)

Then for each street I get a geopoint and run it by TomTom's Reverse Geocoding method of their [Map Toolkit API](http://developer.tomtom.com/io-docs), that gives me the min and max street number values for each of the streets.