# Google Maps API v3 / Get nearby streets

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get nearby streets using Google Maps API v3?

I'm not interested on displaying a map on the screen, I just need to display the 10 top streets close to an already found address.

One solution is pointed out @ [Get nearby street addresses within a radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513443/get-nearby-street-addresses-within-a-radius), but I think Google Maps should provide a solution to this as well, right?

Comment: I ended up using Google Maps and the solution presented @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513443/get-nearby-street-addresses-within-a-radius

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to get streets near an address using the Google Maps API. Your best bet may be in sampling a few points near your address of interest and calling the Geocoding API to get the name of the street.